# How do I extract parts of code into local variables in Kotlin when using Ktor's HTML builder?

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, dsl, ktor

I am trying to understand the HTML builder in Kotlin / Ktor. 
The [example here](https://github.com/Kotlin/ktor/blob/5902c5d393bbab4171e5f92b48a9aa21f4d4d524/ktor-samples/ktor-samples-html/src/org/jetbrains/ktor/samples/html/HtmlApplication.kt#L14) uses the HTML builder to build the result:

```
call.respondHtml {
    head {
        title { +"HTML Application" }
    }
    body {
        h1 { +"Sample application with HTML builders" }
        widget {
            +"Widgets are just functions"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to extract the body into a variable like this:

```
val block: HTML.() -> Unit = {
    head {
        title { +"HTML Application" }
    }
    body {
        h1 { +"Sample application with HTML builders" }
    }
}
call.respondHtml(block)
```

Now I get the following compile error:

```
Error:(37, 22) Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public suspend fun ApplicationCall.respondHtml(status: HttpStatusCode = ..., versions: List<Version> = ..., cacheControl: CacheControl? = ..., block: HTML.() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.jetbrains.ktor.html
public suspend fun ApplicationCall.respondHtml(status: HttpStatusCode = ..., block: HTML.() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.jetbrains.ktor.html
```

When I add the first (optional) argument it works again: `call.respondHtml(HttpStatusCode.OK, block)`.

Why does it not work, when I simply try to extract the body into a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the compiler doesn't like having a mandatory *after* default parameters, unless it is a lambda outside of the braces.

Try to name it:

```
call.respondHtml(block = block)
```

Comment: Using named parameters does not fix it, but the explanation makes sense.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer if it doesn't solve the problem? It may be a nice snippet of information, but if it doesn't actually answer the question, it shouldn't be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

BTW, if what you want is to extract logic, I would recommend using functions. For your example:

```
fun HTML.headAndBody() {
    head {
        title { +"HTML Application" }
    }
    body {
        h1 { +"Sample application with HTML builders" }
        widget {
            +"Widgets are just functions"
        }
    }
}

call.respondHtml {
    headAndBody()
}
```

That way you can even add parameters to your block of html, creating a custom component out of it.

Comment: How does this compare to using the `call.respondHtmlTemplate` approach? What you have here looks more idiomatic to me, but it begs the question, why does Ktor support a templating system when you could just do this already?

Comment: Templates are easier for copy-pasting HTML from the Internet, however the DSL is much more powerful for conditional generation and loops. I prefer mixing up both approaches

Comment: Hmm, the examples I've seen are still using the DSL, though I can't fully work out how to get it to work how I want. This seems like a more intuitive way of handling things. I'm kinda curious how performance will be... but I think I'll deal with that if/when it becomes a problem.